# How to add to and update variables in an if/elif statement in Python?

Tags: python, variables, if-statement

Everything works except the (current_space) does not get updated with the (current_space += rolled_dice). It just updates to the (rolled_dice) value.
What causes this and are there better practices to implement here. Like a class?

```
from random import randint

finish_line = 20
player_1 = raw_input('Enter player 1 name: ')
player_2 = raw_input('Enter player 2 name: ')    
print('\nWelcome ' + player_1 + ' and ' + player_2)
print('\nLet\'s Play!\n')


def roll_1():
    current_space1 = int()
    #print(current_space1)
    roll_dice = raw_input(player_1 + ' roll dice? y or n: ')
    if roll_dice == 'y':
        rolled_dice = (randint(1,6))
        print(player_1 + ' ' + 'rolled a ' + str(rolled_dice))
        if current_space1 != finish_line:
            current_space1 += rolled_dice
            #print(current_space1)
            roll_2()
        elif current_space1 == finish_line:
            print('You are the winner ' + player_1 + '!')
        elif roll_dice == 'n':
            print('Thanks for playing')
        else:
            print('Invalid entry')



def roll_2():
    current_space2 = int()
    roll_dice = raw_input(player_2 + ' roll dice? y or n: ')
    if roll_dice == 'y':
        rolled_dice = (randint(1,6))
        print(player_2 + ' ' + 'rolled a ' + str(rolled_dice))
        if current_space2 != finish_line:
            current_space2 += rolled_dice
            roll_1()
        elif current_space2 == finish_line:
            print('You are the winner ' + player_2 + '!')
        elif roll_dice == 'n':
            print('Thanks for playing')
        else:
            print('Invalid entry')

roll_1()
```

Answer (score 0):

`current_space1` and `current_space2` are *local* variables of the functions `roll_1` and `roll_2` respectively. Those variables get actually incremented by the line `... += rolled_dice` but in the next line you are invoking the function anew which in turn has its own scope where `current_space` is zero at the beginning. This will continue until you reach the max. recursion depth.

Instead you could make those variables `global` and mark them as such with the `global` keyword.

Another approach would be to create a `Player` class

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.current_space = 0
```

and use only one `roll` function together with two `Player` instances which are passed as arguments to that `roll` function. You would then increment `player.current_space += rolled_dice`.

For example:

```
def roll(active_player, passive_player):
    ...
    if active_player.current_space != finish_line:
        active_player.current_space += rolled_dice
        roll(passive_player, active_player)
```

Btw you might also want to rethink when you check a player having reached the target because in your example you first ask to roll and then the player could win from a score which was obtained already in the turn before.

Answer (score 0):

Both `current_space1` and `current_space2` are **local** variables - they are created and initialized when the function enters and available only within the function context, once you leave the function, or enter another function, they are not available. If you want them to be available outside of the function (and increment within multiple function calls) you need to declare them globally:

```
finish_line = 20
player_1 = raw_input('Enter player 1 name: ')
player_2 = raw_input('Enter player 2 name: ')
current_space1 = 0
current_space2 = 0

# ...

def roll1():
    global current_space1  # instead of current_space1 = int()
    # rest of the function ...

def roll2():
    global current_space2  # instead of current_space2 = int()
    # rest of the function ...
```

Having said that, using global variable is not considered a good practice. For example, see this [post and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil).